# How to prevent thead to be printed on all pages

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to know if it's possible, when a user begins to print an html page, to prevent the `thead` of a table to be printed on all the pages ?

It's because I use `page-break-after: always;` on an element situated before my table, and because of that my table header is also printed on the first page...

I cannot replace my `thead` by a `tr` because a hard part of my code lays on that `thead`.

Comment: can't you add <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print"> to your head and in print.css add a display:none to the elements you don't want to print?

Comment: No, I can't, because these elements does not appear directly on my html page.
It is an inner behaviour of the thead nodes that automatically print them on all the pages.

Answer (score 2):

I used [this method](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/5134#issuecomment-964936764) and it worked:

```scss
@media print {
  thead {
    display: table-row-group
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With THEAD you cannot do this. But you can try to apply `display: table-row` to `<thead>` but it doesn't work in all browsers

> When long tables are printed, the head and foot information may be **repeated on each page** that contains table data ([official docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-THEAD))